# Проблема в реализации объекта

Tags: java, ооп

Данная программа в каждом слове текста удаляет такие же буквы, как первая.

Пример:

> [In]:Hehllo, what's up - Hah.
>
> [Out]:Hello, what's up - Ha

Но я столкнулся с проблемой в пунктуации.Я не знаю как класс `Пунктуация` связать с классом `Слово`/`Предложение`, чтобы, допустим знак '-' не был `Словом`, так как у меня слово отделено пробелами с обоих сторон. И чтобы после каждого предложения ставилась точка\вопрос. знак - объект `Пунктуация`.

Код:

```
    public class Lab4 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String s = "Размер или длина массива — это общее количество элементов в массиве." +
                   " Размер массива           задаётся при создании массива и не может быть изменён в дальнейшем," +
                   " другими словами нельзя убрать элементы из массива или добавить их туда, но" +
                   " можно в существующие элементы           присвоить новые значения.";
        Text text = new Text(s);
        System.out.println("Initial text:");
        System.out.println(text.getAllText());
        StringBuilder newText = new StringBuilder();
        Sentence c;
        Word w;
        for(int i = 0; i < text.getSentences().length; i++){
            c = new Sentence(text.getSentenceByIndex(i));
            for(int j = 0; j < c.getWords().length; j++){
                w = new Word(c.getWords()[j].getAllWord());
                newText.append(w.removeChars());
                newText.append(" ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(newText);
    }
}

    class Text {
            private Sentence[] sentences;
            private String allText;
    
            public Text(String allText){
                String newAllText = allText.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
                setAllText(newAllText);
                sentences = new Sentence[amountOfSentences()];
                fillUpSentenceArray();
            }
    
            public int amountOfSentences(){
                return allText.split("\\.!?").length;
            }
    
            public void fillUpSentenceArray(){
                for (int i = 0; i < amountOfSentences(); i++){
                    sentences[i] = new Sentence((allText.split("\\.!?"))[i]);
                }
            }
    
            public String getAllText() {
                return allText;
            }
    
            public Sentence[] getSentences() {
                return sentences;
            }
    
            public String getSentenceByIndex(int i){
                return sentences[i].getAllSentence();
            }
    
            public void setAllText(String allText) {
                this.allText = allText;
            }
    }
    class Sentence {
        private Word[] words;
        private Punctuation[] punctuations;
        private String allSentence;
    
        public Sentence(String allSentence){
            this.allSentence = allSentence;
            words = new Word[countAmountOfWords()];
            fillUpWordsArray();
            punctuations = new Punctuation[countAmountOfPunct()];
            fillUpPunctArray();
        }
    
        public int countAmountOfWords(){
            return allSentence.split(" ").length;
        }
    
        public int countAmountOfPunct(){
            StringBuilder a = new StringBuilder();
            for(int i = 0; i < allSentence.length(); i++){
                if(allSentence.toCharArray()[i] == ',' || allSentence.toCharArray()[i] == '.' ||
                        allSentence.toCharArray()[i] == '-'){
                    a.append(allSentence.toCharArray()[i]);
                }
            }
            return a.length();
        }
    
        public void fillUpWordsArray(){
            for(int i = 0; i < countAmountOfWords(); i++){
                words[i] = new Word((allSentence.split(" "))[i]);
            }
        }
    
        public void fillUpPunctArray(){
            char[] charr = allSentence.toCharArray();
            for(int i = 0; i < countAmountOfPunct(); i++){
                if(charr[i] == ',' || charr[i] == '.' || charr[i] == '-'){
                    punctuations[i] = new Punctuation(charr[i]);
                }
            }
        }
    
        public Word[] getWords() {
            return words;
        }
    
        public String getAllSentence() {
            return allSentence;
        }
    }
    class Word {
        private Letter[] letters;
        private String allWord;
    
        public Word(String allWord){
            this.allWord = allWord;
            letters = new Letter[countLengthofWord()];
            fillUpLetterArray();
        }
    
        public int countLengthofWord(){
            return allWord.length();
        }
    
        public void fillUpLetterArray(){
            for (int i = 0; i < countLengthofWord(); i++){
                letters[i] = new Letter(allWord.toCharArray()[i]);
            }
        }
    
        public StringBuilder removeChars(){
            StringBuilder upDatedWord = new StringBuilder(countLengthofWord());
            if (allWord.isEmpty()){
                allWord = " ";
            }
            char distChar = allWord.charAt(0);
            upDatedWord.append(distChar);
            for (int i = 0; i < allWord.length(); i++){
                if (allWord.isEmpty()){
                    continue;
                }
                if (Character.toLowerCase(distChar) != Character.toLowerCase(allWord.charAt(i))){
                    upDatedWord.append(allWord.charAt(i));
                }
            }
            this.allWord = upDatedWord.toString();
            return upDatedWord;
        }
    
        public String getAllWord() {
            return allWord;
        }
    }
    class Punctuation {
        private char symbol;
    
        public Punctuation(char symbol){
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }
    
        public char getSymbol() {
            return symbol;
        }
    
        public void setSymbol(char symbol) {
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }
    }
    class Letter {
        private char letter;
    
        public Letter(char letter){
            this.letter = letter;
    
        }
    
        public char getLetter() {
            return letter;
        }
    
        public void setLetter(char letter) {
            this.letter = letter;
        }
    
    }



/*public void fillUpSentencePartArray(){
        boolean flag = false;

        for(int i = 0; i < allSentence.toCharArray().length; i++){
            if(Character.isLetter(allSentence.toCharArray()[i])){
                char[] temp = new char[20];
                temp[i] = allSentence.toCharArray()[i];
                if(flag){
                    Word wordToAdd = new Word(temp.toString());
                    sentenceParts[i] = wordToAdd;
                }
            }
            else if(allSentence.toCharArray()[i] == '.' || allSentence.toCharArray()[i] == ','){
                Punctuation znakToAdd = new Punctuation(allSentence.toCharArray()[i]);
                sentenceParts[i] = znakToAdd;
            }
            else flag = true;
        }
    }
*/
```

Comment: Почему бы Вам не создать интерфейс SentencePart без методов. Пусть его инкапсулируют Word и Punctuation. Тогда в классе Sentence можно использовать SentencePart[] вместо Word[]. Это поможет сохранить порядок слов и знаков препинания в предложении.

Comment: Тоесть объект Пунктуация обрабатывать потом как Слово?

Comment: Что понимаете под термином обрабатывать? Если хотите "обрабатывать" только слова что бы ни понималось под этим термином, можно проверять класс объекта (instanceof) и если это Word, то кастовать объект к нему и "обрабатывать"

Comment: Нам в интерфейсе нужно сделать массив слов и пунктуации?

Comment: Можете написать как начать? Я суть уловил, но недопонимаю как реализовать...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Могу и написать:

```
interface SentensePart {}
class Word implements SentensePart {...}
class Punctuation implements SentensePart {...}
class Sentence {
  //private Word[] words;
  //private Punctuation[] punctuations;
  //вместо этих двух строк с массивами классов используем один массив с общим интерфейсом:
  private SentensePart[] sentenseParts;
  //Последний элемент в этом массиве должен принадлежать классу Punctuation
```

Чтобы понимать что у нас слово можно воспользоваться instaceof и кастованием к классу:

```
SentensePart sentensePart = ...;
if (sentensePart instanceof Word) {
  Word word = (Word) sentensePart;
  //и далее работаем уже с типом word
```

Не вчитывался в Ваши методы, но что могу еще заметить:

1. зачем вам вообще класс Letter? Чем не устраивает Character?
2. Punctuation содержит только один символ. А многоточие чем обидели?
3. может быть не только знаком пунктуации, но и дефисом.

UPD. На комметарий:

```
public void fillUpSentencePartArray(){
    boolean flag = false;

    for(int i = 0; i < allSentence.toCharArray().length; i++){
        //можно воспользоваться функцией allSentence.charAt(i)
        if(Character.isLetter(allSentence.toCharArray()[i])){
            //Здесь вы создаете новый массив при каждой новой букве, 
            //старый ссылка массив при этом теряется. Вместо массива
            //фиксированной длины имхо вообще лучше использовать 
            //StringBuilder. Объявлять его или массив надо до цикла, 
            //чтобы ссылка была действительна при разных итерациях цикла
            char[] temp = new char[20];

            //В следующей строке вы обращаетесь к элементу массива temp, 
            //с длиной 20, по индексу i который, может быть до 
            //allSentence.length
            temp[i] = allSentence.toCharArray()[i];

            if(flag){
                Word wordToAdd = new Word(temp.toString());
                //здесь опять ошибка с индексом. i - это индекс символа, 
                //а не индекс в массиве sentenceParts.
                sentenceParts[i] = wordToAdd;
            }
        }
        else if(allSentence.toCharArray()[i] == '.' || allSentence.toCharArray()[i] == ','){
            Punctuation znakToAdd = new Punctuation(allSentence.toCharArray()[i]);
            //та же ошибка с индексом.
            sentenceParts[i] = znakToAdd;

        }
        else flag = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: 1.Так гласит задание.
2.Не дописал, так как сначала хотел проверить на работоспособность.

Comment: А как нам заполнять массив? Чтобы все в правильном порядке заполнялось

Comment: Можно парсить текст посимвольно

Comment: в моем коде Слово может быть со знаком пунктуации, а мне нужно, чтобы они отдельно были (например ```туда,``` - это слово)
и как мы можем парсить, если у нас массив объектов?

Comment: Так и в чем сложность: прочитали символ, если не пробел и не знак пунктуации, то добавляем к текущему слову. Если пробел - значит слово закончилось, и добавляем его к массиву sentensePart. Если знак препинания, то добавляем сперва слово, потом знак препинания.

Comment: Задаем цикл по длине Предложения, а как нам символы прибавлять к слову?

Comment: Например так: обнаружили первую букву - начало слова, создали пустой массив букв и добавили туда букву; прочитали следующую - добавили в массив; нашли конец слова - создали объект Word из этого массива.

Comment: Добавил функцию добавления в конце моего вопроса.Почему выдает исключение ```ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException```?

Comment: добавил комментарии в ответ. Кроме описанных, есть ошибки в логике метода, например, при нахождении знака пунктуации, слово не создается.

Comment: а почему это ```sentenceParts[i] = wordToAdd;``` неправильно? разве по другому мы можем в массив добавить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74432/discussion-between---and-artem-aleksandrovich).